# Jackson update from 1.7.1 to 2.8.6 - JsonTypeInfo subtype deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm currently upgrading a system from Jackson 1.7.1 to 2.8.6. I have something like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
public interface LeSerializable extends Serializable
{
    ...
}

public interface Resource extends LeSerializable
{
    ...
}

public class ResourceV2 extends Resource implements IResourceV2
{
    ...
}
```

The serialization is working fine, creating an attribute type with the defined Class, however, for the deserialization I have the error:

**Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class com.model.LeSerializable)**

with:

```
final ResourceV2 retObject = mapper.readValue(json, ResourceV2.class);
```

Any suggestions that might have changed between both versions?

Comment: If the `readValue` example you post fails the error message will end with `(for class com.model.ResourceV2)` not `LeSerializable`. And that will happen if there is no field like`"type":"ResourceV2"` in the JSON.